# How to keep a task running when app is backgrounded on iOS using Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, background

So I have a helper method that I run on iOS to execute a background task in my app. The call sends a message to our backend that pushes a notification to the device to open a separate app, that the user hits accept on to do two factor authentication.

Issue is that when the SimpleCall is running, the user hits the notification (or home) and the Task is immediately cancelled. The logic USED to work in previous versions of iOS/Xamarin but no longer does. I tried to run the background helper at lower levels of code but the results are the same.

Is there a better way to implement these type of tasks perhaps because it's making a blocking network call?

The call looks something like this:

```
public async Task<Response> SimpleCall()
    {
        return await GetNetworkResponseAsync(() => {
                var response = _loginHelper.Tasks.User.WaitForAppPush(...);             
            return response;
        });
    }
public override async Task RunInBackground(string name, Func<Task> taskToKeepRunning)
    {

        nint taskId = 0;
        taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(name, new Action(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exhausted time");
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
        }));
        await taskToKeepRunning.Invoke();

        Debug.WriteLine("Completed task");
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
    }

public void Run(){
     Response result = null;
        var act = new Func<Task>(async () =>
        { 

                try
                {
                    var pushResult = await _authService.SimpleCall();
                    result = pushResult?.Data ?? null;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                Debug.WriteLine("Act Call:" + ex.Message);
                }

        });

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            await _backgroundService.RunInBackground("Login", act); 

        }
```

}

Comment: Hi , when enter background you can invoke `DidEnterBackground` method to add Task in iOS. Here is [the lifecycle for Xamarin.iOS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo).

Comment: I think part of the issue is that I'm wrapping things in Tasks and using async await. It's one of those things that in 99% of the app we run our network calls off main thread in an async call, but I get the feeling that this is a time when we shouldn't be. Seems to be locking the UI thread but its at least not getting cancelled.

Comment: May be check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios ?

Comment: @ChristopherRichmond This should run in a thread out of UI Thred , just monitoring in background .